# QB64 _MOUSEMOVEMENT not reading any input

Tags: mouse, qb64

I am using Ubuntu but am not very experienced with it yet, so this might be an Ubuntu problem instead of a QB64 problem, so I also posted it to [askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com). Anyway, I wanted to make a program with mouse input, but although `_MOUSEINPUT` would return -1, `_MOUSEMOVEMENTX` and `_MOUSEMOVEMENTY` would only return 0, although `_MOUSEX` and.`_MOUSEY` would function properly. I haven't used mouse input in QB64 all that much before, so I was still learning how to use it.

To make sure I wasn't just going crazy, I used one of the sample programs off of the QB64 Wiki that use `_MOUSEMOVEMENT`:

> ```
> SCREEN 13, , 1, 0
> DO: _LIMIT 200
>  DO WHILE _MOUSEINPUT
>    x = x + _MOUSEMOVEMENTX
>    y = y + _MOUSEMOVEMENTY
>  LOOP
>  x = (x + 320) MOD 320 'keeps object on screen
>  y = (y + 200) MOD 200 'remove if off screen moves are desired
>  CLS
>  CIRCLE (x, y), 20
>  PCOPY 1, 0
> LOOP UNTIL INKEY$ <> "" 'press any key to exit
> ```

And this is what it does:

> [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pM3I6.png)

If I move the mouse, nothing happens.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!